# Pandas - Comparing Lists in two data frames of different size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames as follows. The second column of each data frame is of type object. They contain a list.

```
DF1
       ID, WORDLIST,          TAGS       
        1   air, water, fire  []
        2   bulb, light, ray  []
        3   chair table       []


DF2
    TAG  WORDLIST
     A   water, ice, liquid
     B   bulb, glass, ray
     C   water, fire
     D   lock, key
```

Now I need to compare these data frames. For each row in DF1, I need to check all the rows in DF2. If wordlist from DF1 and DF2 have common words, I need to assign the tag from DF2.

My resut should look like

```
Result : Updated DF1

        id1, WORDLIST,           TAGS
         1   air, water, fire    A, C
         2   bulb, light, ray    B
         3   chair, table         <Empty>
```

**EDIT**
I achieved this with the following code

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = [
        {'ID':1,'WORDLIST': ['air', 'water', 'fire'] , 'TAGS' : []},
        {'ID':2, 'WORDLIST': ['bulb', 'light', 'ray'] , 'TAGS' : [] },
        {'ID':3,'WORDLIST':['chair', 'table'], 'TAGS' : []}
    ]

    df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)

    data = [
        {'TAG':'A','WORDLIST': ['water', 'ice', 'liquid']},
        {'TAG':'B', 'WORDLIST': ['bulb', 'glass', 'ray'] },
        {'TAG':'C','WORDLIST':['water', 'fire']},
        {'TAG':'D','WORDLIST':['lock', 'key']}
    ]

    df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)


    print("DF1", df1)
    print("DF2", df2)


    def getTagForList(df1words):
        tags=[]
        for index, row in df2.iterrows():
            df2words = row['WORDLIST']
            if(bool(set(df1words).intersection(df2words) )):
                tags.append(row['TAG'])    
        return tags


    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
            tags = getTagForList(row['WORDLIST'])
            print(tags)
            df1.at[index,'TAGS']=tags

    print("Updated DF1", df1)
```

But is there a better and cleaner solution for this which is more efficient? Can we avoid iterating one data frame for all rows of the other data frame?

Comment: Show us some code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: have you tried pd.merge_asof

Comment: I havent. I am new to Pandas. That is why my code appears to be more conventional than leveraging the Pandas features. Could you please help out?